# How can I collect my API data in an Array in flutter?

Tags: json, flutter, api, dart

Basically I want to collect my API data in an array AND add new data to my array every time I'm calling my API, then use `map` function to construct my dynamic row...I hope you understood my problem.

My code, try to construct dynamic row by collecting data in an Array

```
 Future<void> GetTestFee() async {
var jsonResponse;
if (encTestId.isNotEmpty) {
  var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://getrbi.in/api/agtyi/GetTestFee"),
      body: ({
        'EncPartnerId': encLabId,
        'EncTestId': encTestId, 

      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    print("Correct");
    print(response.body);
    jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    print(jsonResponse);
    getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);

  } else {
    throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
  }
} else {
  throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
}
//throw Exception("Faild to fetch");
return GetTestFee();
```

}

JSON resresponse

```
      {
  "EncPartnerId": "LEuT1eIlpLiuiiyAAkZme3wpQ==",
  "EncTestId": "U4exk+vfMGrn7cjNUa/kji==",
  "Fee": "100",
  "DiscountedFee": "80",
  "BookingFee": "50"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your model to list:

```
List<GetTestFeeMap> reponseModel =[]
```

And after getting you response add it into list

```
var response = await http.post(
      Uri.parse("http://ytyttiiiuiu.in/api/medboapi/GetTestFee"),
      body: ({
        'EncPartnerId': encLabId, // can use for test run "LEuT1eIlpLEMAAkZme3wpQ==",
        'EncTestId': encTestId,  // "U4exk+vfMGrn7cjNUa/PBw=="

      }));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
print("Correct");
print(response.body);
jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body.toString());
print(jsonResponse);
getTestFeeObj=GetTestFeeMap.fromJson(jsonResponse);
 reponseModel.add(getTestFeeObj)
```

I hope I undrestand right.